# Symetric buttons css style

Tags: css

I can't find or determine which css allows me to do two buttons in symmetry or justified align..
I can't remember..

I put you a picture that shows what I want to do

the two buttons are supposed to take the full width available

[image]

Comment: display: `inline-block` to place them one aside other. For the size just put `width: 50%`. Put each pair inside a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.align-row {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  width:100%;
  }
  
  .box-container {
    width:400px !important;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    border:1px solid #eee;
    height:200px;
  }
  
  .btn, .btn-wrap {
    width:100% !important;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="box-container">
<div class="align-row">
  <div class="btn-wrap">
      <a class="btn btn-success rounded-0">hello</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="btn-wrap">
      <a class="btn btn-secondary rounded-0">Goodbye</a>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you everyone
thanks to you I was able to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with grid

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
button {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 1em;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1em;
}
button:first-child {
  background: royalblue;
  color: white;
}
button:last-child {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>For rent</button>
  <button>For sale</button>
</div>
```